# Pregunta con schedule de Laravel

Tags: laravel, schedule

Buenas estoy usando schedule en laravel para que ciertas tareas se hagan en tiempo, lo que basicamente hace es ejecutar un comando, todo bien hasta ahí, el comando me funciona perfectamente.

```
$schedule->command('Alerta:Tarea')->everyminute();
```

Ahora me surgen dos problemas con esto, cuando lo ejecute en la terminal con php artisan run se ejecuta y cumple la función pero solo una vez, después de que se ejecuta al minuto ya no lo vuelve a repetir mas, por otra parte tengo un segundo problema, muy aparte de lo dicho necesito que se ejecute entre ciertas horas y cada hora, entonces use esto.

```
$schedule->command('Alerta:Tarea')
                    ->hourly()
                    ->between('7:00', '22:00');
```

Pero en vez de correrme una sola vez, me aparece "No scheduled commands are ready to run.", como podria solucionarlo, me recomendaron mucho usar esto, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo funcionar. Puse mi zona horaria y sucede lo mismo, solo me funciona con everyminute() y solo una vez y no funciona con los demás comandos. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que los schedule funcionen necesitas un cron general que ejecute el comando de forma periódica, este cron debe ser ejecutado por el sistema, en la documentación tienes un ejemplo para Linux:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Luego en el caso de tu schedule, estas indicando que se ejecute una vez cada hora entre las 7:00 y las 22:00, se va a comprobar que ha pasado por lo menos 1h desde la última vez que se ejecutó y que estamos dentro del rango indicado.

```
$schedule->command('Alerta:Tarea')
                ->hourly() // cada hora
                ->between('7:00', '22:00');  // entre las 7.00 y las 22.00
```